# Update multiple rows in datatable without loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have two datatable with conditions in application and want some processing for multiple rows to update column value.

For example:

I have datatable1 with 10000 rows. I want to filter rows by datatable.select("condition") and as per condition, I want to update row values.

If for any condition, I found 20 rows from datatable. I want to update those 20 records in one shot. Not in any loop. I have datarow array for those values to update in datable.

Comment: How exactly do you want to update the rows? This seems like something you could probably do with a dynamic query using the ``in`` keyword.

Comment: How do you think you can do it without a loop? If framework provides some method also it will be internally doing a loop!

Comment: maybe he means with lambda expressions.. but there will be anyway a loop

Comment: @Sriram - Yes, I know but better way or anything or any method which I am not aware if! Thats the reason I posted question.

Comment: @darkdog - Thanks for your understanding. Something similar I am looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try out the following linq,

```
DataTable recTable = new DataTable();

// do stuff to populate table

recTable.Select(string.Format("[code] = '{0}'", someName)).ToList<DataRow>().ForEach(r => r["Color"] = colorValue);
```

You can substitute  your columns and values here...

Comment: Loop is far far efficient than this

Comment: this is just a way to update without using loops externally. if performance is a constraint, then go for Parallel For.

Comment: Thanks for inputs and suggestions.

Comment: string.Format("[Code]='{0}'",somename) what is code here and what is somename. are you updating the value of code

Answer (score 2):

To Update Row With Multiple Condition use This

```
    datatable.Select(string.Format("[lineNo]='{0}' and [Position]>='{1}' ", lineNo, Position)).ToList<DataRow>().ForEach(r => r["Linetext"] ="Sample Text" );
```

Comment: This is just a fancier way of still doing a loop - Note the 'ForEach(...)'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to default a column value with `abc` use **Expression**, then you could use the below code.

```
dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName").Expression = "'abc'";
```

In case if you need to pass the value dynamically using a variable, you could use the below code.

```
string str = "abc";
dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName").Expression = "'" + str + "'";
```