# EF - Update multiple rows in database without using foreach loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My test code:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
  string fromUser = ""; //sender
  string toUser = ""; //receiver

  var messages = db.Message.Where(x => x.FromUser == fromUser && x.ToUser == toUser)
                 .ToList();

  foreach (var message in messages)
  {
    message.IsRead = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

My question: is there another way to update database without using `foreach` loop in that case?

p/s: I'd been reference these questions but all of them didn't solve my problem:

- [Update multiple rows in datatable without loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830113/update-multiple-rows-in-datatable-without-loop)
- [updating multiple records in database with linq to sql without loop, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663756/updating-multiple-records-in-database-with-linq-to-sql-without-loop-is-it-possi)
- [Update multiple rows without looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407910/update-multiple-rows-without-looping)

Comment: Move the `SaveChanges()` outside of the `for` loop

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't need to SaveChanges() on each iteration. That will hit the database multiple times. Try:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
  string fromUser = ""; //sender
  string toUser = ""; //receiver
  var messages = db.Message.Where(x => x.FromUser == fromUser && x.ToUser == toUser)
                 .ToList();
  messages.ForEach(m => m.IsRead = true);
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Creating a list and lambda just to call a method which internally is a loop. Crazy people.

Comment: Well, the bigger point is certainly the single database call. Some would argue the lambda looks cleaner (it's a resharper recommended refactoring). Crazy is a little harsh IMO.

Comment: @SteveGreene The comment was not for your or your solution, I understand that was the OP request. Indeed a single database call is the point, but not from the post title, which moves the focus on the unimportant thing. `List<T>.ForEach` is a mistake - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: Definitely debatable. http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/04/23/c-linq-vs-foreach---round-1.aspx

Comment: Simple and Direct approached and saved alot of process time. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Just to update Steve's answer, in newer EF (current EF Core 3.1.3) you can do it all as one statement.

```
await db.Message.Where(m => m.FromUser == fromUser && m.ToUser == toUser).ForEachAsync(m => m.IsRead = true);
await db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```