# C# Entity Framework what is the time complexity of .Find(id) method

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

What is the time complexity of the `.Find(id)` method? Is it a bad idea to loop over a list of id's and use `.Find()`?

Also is it possible to 'find' multiple id's in the same query?

```
foreach (var id in idList)
{
    var task = _model.Tasks.Find(id);
    Save(task,task.id);
}
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Take a step back and explain your _underlying_ problem.

Comment: `Find` performs a `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = x`. If you want to bring all entities for a range of IDs, do a single query => `_model.Tasks.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.id))`

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: @jarlh Sometimes Entity Framework talks to SQL I guess...  :P

Comment: its very rare that you would want to find many different items which are not related in some form. So you would find them based on a shared commonality. Anyway you should not have a save inside of a for loop... this is probably your actual problem with regards to performance in this instance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107936/ef-update-multiple-rows-in-database-without-using-foreach-loop/34108011#34108011

Comment: Don't save in a loop.

Comment: sorry for confusion, the save is my own method that does something quite complicated. Thanks @CamiloTerevinto thats what I was looking for, I cant upvote you because I have no points on this account

Comment: I think you can accept the answer, though. I will up vote for you. It is a good answer @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: BTW, does your Save method involve a TAP pattern ( System.Threading.Tasks.Task) ? If so, you may want to rethink using it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you are using the elements (and how many there are), you may find it much better to load all entities at once:

```
// given List<int> idList
var tasks = _model.Tasks.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.id))

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    Save(task, task.id);
}
```

Notice that `Find` performs a `Where` with the Primary Key, so you have to be careful if the entity does not have a Primary Key or if it has a composite one. You also don't get any compile-time safety of the type of the key (i.e you could pass a `string` to an entity with an `int` PK and find out at only run-time).
Of course, if the list is big enough, you may run into an `OutOfMemoryException` by bringing all data at once.