# C# EF Doesn't save multiple records using ForEach

Tags: entity-framework

Good day guys,

I'm trying to save a multiple records.

I've done my research but none of them actually works on my end.

Here's my code:

```
var dataToUpdate = context.Employees.ToList(); 

using(var db = context){
   var department= "IT";

   dataToUpdate.ForEach(x=>{
       x.department = department;
   });

   db.SaveChanges()
}
```

Source here: [EF - Update multiple rows in database without using foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107936/ef-update-multiple-rows-in-database-without-using-foreach-loop) but it doesn't work.

I tried to put breakpoints and try catch and my breakpoint goes to `db.SaveChanges` without error. But when I check the data from db, no changes have occurred.

Comment: what is `dataToUpdate` ?

Comment: it is from my list

Comment: It is clear that `dataToUpdate` did not come from this `db`. So it is not tracked here.  Your question is far from complete.

Comment: I've updated the code @Petaflop & Henk

Comment: A `using {}` on a copied variable? Now your code looks artificial an hard to believe.

Comment: @Petaflop - No.

Comment: I've removed the `ToList()` but still it doesn't work

Comment: I done removing the `using ...` but still, it doesn't work

Comment: If you want to modify all rows in a table execute a simple `Update Employees SET Department=@x`. ORM's are meant to work with entities, not perform batch updates. There's nothing to be gained by loading all data on the client only to send them back with a simple change

Comment: I'm using EF @PanagiotisKanavos and I can't just create a query string like that. The multiple saving also happens when a user makes a changes

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy yes you can execute raw SQL with EF. You shouldn't use an ORM at *all* for such a query. It has nothing to do with *objects*, entities or mapping to tables

Comment: It has to be about `[entity-framework-6]` ___or___ `[entity-framework-core]`, it can't be about both.

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at! you are pulling and updating data from two different contexts. Actually it should be from same context as follows:

```
using(var db = context)
{
  var dataToUpdate = db.Employees.ToList();

   var department= "IT";

   dataToUpdate.ForEach(x=>{
       x.department = department;
   });

   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Typical missing semicolon after `db.SaveChanges()` :)

Comment: @Petaflop Oh! Thanks.